# Completely ignored by headerLeft on nested Stacks

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm want to render the `headerLeft` conditionally, but it doesn't matter what I do it simply ignores me.

[image]

Follow my code:

```
return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {screens.map((screen, index) => {
        const isQuestion = screen.screen === "Question";

        return (
          <Stack.Screen
            key={index}
            name={screen.name}
            component={getTemplate}
            initialParams={{ index, screen }}
          
            options={{
              ...DefaultNavigationOptions()[screen.theme],
              headerBackTitleVisible: false,
              title: lessonName,
              headerTintColor: isQuestion ? 'red' : '', // <- works!

              // headerBackImage: Variable.icons.circle, // <- attempt that did not work
              
              // headerLeft: () => { // <- attempt that did not work
              //   return null;
              // },

              headerLeft: props => ( // <- not working
                <HeaderBackButton
                  {...props}
                  disabled={true}  
                />
              ),

              headerRight: () => ( // <- works!
                <HeaderButton
                  handleOnPress={() => onExit()}
                  icon={Variable.icons.exit}
                  theme={screen.theme}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
```

What I trying for now is simply to change the `headerLeft` somehow, just to see if it is working so after I can make it conditional.

Already try to find a solution in the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator and also in other questions done here on stackoverflow, but no luck so far.

```
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.2",
 "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^5.0.5",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.8.0",
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that I was using `const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();` instead of const `Stack = createStackNavigator();`

More info here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/ if someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Well i had a similar problem as you, but my solution instead of returning NULL was returning an empty text. That did the work. Why this? Well after reading the documentation it says clearly whatever you write there will replace the back button, so why not an empty Text. XD

```
//? For some reason NULL wasnt working, so i went with an empty <Text>. 
        <Stack.Screen 
name="Dashboard" 
component={DashboardScreen} 
options={{headerLeft: () => <Text></Text>}}
/>
```